# Rebuild android.jar with appcompat library on device in Termux

Tags: android, aapt, termux, dx, ecj

This project https://github.com/BuildAPKs/buildAPKs builds APKs on device in Termux in Android.  Frequent errors are related to appcompat when compiling without artifacts, i.e., `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.`

When building with libraries enabled the APK file size is much larger, i.e. `com.google.android.divideandconquer.apk` builds to **35.4K without libraries** enabled in BuildAPK on a smartphone.  It is about **500K when built with libraries** enabled.  Rebuilding the aapt, dx and/or ecj packages on device to include the appcompat library in the jar files might resolve this file output size issue.

How can building packages aapt, dx and/or ecj to include appcompat in the jar files be accomplished in Termux on a smartphone?  If it is not possible to build these packages in Termux and Termux PRoot on handheld, how can this be done on a traditional Linux box?

Comment: In this question, `ecj` is not referring to the Eclipse Compiler for Java, is it? Please check your tags.

Comment: `$ ecj -version                                                                          Eclipse Compiler for Java(TM) v20161117-1814, 3.12.2, Copyright IBM Corp 2000, 2015. All rights reserved.`  It's the one packaged for Termux.